# NJS-024: memory allocation failed in OracleDB - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to run a query using OracleDB with Nodejs to get the view populated in the UI but I get a **NJS-024: memory allocation failed** error. Can someone help me out? The view contains 120 columns in total and when I query the view in SQL Developer, it works just fine.

ConnectionPool.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var poolMap = {};

var logger = require(path.join(global.root + '/app/util/logger.js'))();

function createPool(poolName, config, callback) {
    oracledb.createPool(
        config,
        function(err, p) {
            if (err){
                logger.error(err);
                return;
            }

            poolMap[poolName] = p;

            callback(poolMap[poolName]);
        }
    );
}

function getPool(poolName) {
    return poolMap[poolName];
}

module.exports = {
    createPool: createPool,
    getPool: getPool
};
```

This is my poolAttributes:

```
var pool;
oracledb.prefetchRows = 10000;
oracledb.maxRows = 400000;

var poolAttrs = {
    user: dbcfg.username,
    password: dbcfg.password,
    connectString: dbcfg.connectionString,
    connectionClass : 'Report API',
    poolMin : 3,
    poolMax : 10,
    poolIncrement: 2,
    poolTimeout : 600 //seconds
};

connectionPool.createPool("Reports", poolAttrs, function(connPool){
    pool = connPool;
    logger.info("Pool created by reports.");
});
```

This is my code:

```
router.post('/report/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body,
        startRow = data.startRow,
        numRows = data.numRows,
        sortCol = data.sortCol,
        sortDir = data.sortDir;

    var countQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' +
        'FROM this_view ' ;

    var query = 'SELECT * ' +
        'FROM this_view' ;

    var seg,
        orderBy,
        offset;

    orderBy = ' ORDER BY UPPER(' + sortCol + ') ' + sortDir;
    offset = ' OFFSET ' + startRow + ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + numRows + ' ROWS ONLY';

    query += orderBy;
    query += offset;

    logger.info("Begin: " + (new Date().toString()));

    async.parallel({
        rows: function (callback) {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            logger.info("Begin Connection: " + (new Date().toString()));
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err.message);
                return;
            }

            logger.info("Begin execute: " + (new Date().toString()));

            connection.execute(
                query,
                {},
                {
                    resultSet: true,
                    prefetchRows: 1000
                },
                function (err, results) {
                    logger.info("End execute: " + (new Date().toString()));
                    var rowsProcessed = 0;
                    var startTime;
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(err.message);
                        callback("Something broke in the first thing");
                        doRelease(connection);
                        return;
                    }
                    var procJson = [];

                    function fetchRowsFromRS(connection, resultSet, numRows) {
                        resultSet.getRows(
                            numRows,  // get this many rows
                            function (err, rows) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                    doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
                                } else if (rows.length >= 0) {
                                    /**
                                     *  For each row in the result, pushes a new object to the rows array
                                     *  In each new object, the key is assigned and the result row value set
                                     */
                                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                                        procJson.push({});
                                        console.log(procJson);
                                        for (var j = 0; j < resultSet.metaData.length; j++) {
                                            procJson[i][resultSet.metaData[j].name.toLowerCase()] = rows[i][j];
                                        }
                                    }

                                    //TODO: Add null handling
                                    logger.info("Send JSON: " + (new Date().toString()));
                                    logger.info("JSON Sent: " + (new Date().toString()));
                                    if (rows.length === numRows) // might be more rows
                                        fetchRowsFromRS(connection, resultSet, numRows);
                                    else
                                        doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
                                } else { // no rows
                                    doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    fetchRowsFromRS(connection, result.resultSet, numRows);
                    callback(null, procJson);
                });
        });
    },
        totalRows: function (callback) {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                logger.info("Begin Connection: " + (new Date().toString()));
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err.message);
                    return;
                }

                logger.info("Begin execute: " + (new Date().toString()));

                connection.execute(
                    countQuery,
                    function (err, result) {
                        logger.info("End execute: " + (new Date().toString()));
                        if (err) {
                            logger.error(err.message);
                            callback("Something broke");
                            doRelease(connection);
                            return;
                        }

                        logger.info("Send JSON: " + (new Date().toString()));
                        console.log(result.rows);
                        callback(null, result.rows[0][0]);
                        logger.info("JSON Sent: " + (new Date().toString()));

                        doRelease(connection);
                    });
            });
        }
    }, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            logger.error(err);
        }

        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

If rows.length >=0 and if the query returns 0 results, I get this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much memory does your Node.js server have? You're setting maxRows very high and grabbing all the data in a single shot. This is likely causing you to run out of memory. Generally, the key is to balance round trips (which you want to reduce) with memory usage (which goes up as round trips are reduced.

You'll want to leverage the ResultSet API, which allows you to stream a read-consistent view of data in smaller chunks. Have a look at this for ideas: https://jsao.io/2015/07/an-overview-of-result-sets-in-the-nodejs-driver/

Rather than buffer the data in the Node.js server (which would lead to the same problem), you'll want to stream it down to the http request.

Finally, but perhaps most importantly, note that your code is currently open to SQL injection. Values that come in from users via req.body cannot be trusted. They must either be bound in using bind variables OR sanitized using something like dbms_assert.

Only values (like numRows) can be bound in. Identifiers (like sortCol) have to be sanitized. You'll likely want to do the sanitization in Node.js, so here's a really basic check that should help.

You could create an "assert" module:

```
function simpleSqlName(name) {
  if (name.length > 30) {
    throw new Error('Not simple SQL');
  }

  // Fairly generic, but effective. Would need to be adjusted to accommodate quoted identifiers,
  // schemas, etc.
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9#_$]+$/.test(name)) {
    throw new Error('Not simple SQL');
  }

  return name;
}

module.exports.simpleSqlName = simpleSqlName;

function validSortOrder(order) {
  if (order !== 'desc' && order !== 'asc') {
    throw new Error('Not valid sort order');
  }

  return order;
}

module.exports.validSortOrder = validSortOrder;
```

Then your code would look more like this (notice I'm using both the assert module and bind variables):

```
let assert = require('assert.js');  

router.post('/report/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body,
        startRow = data.startRow,
        numRows = data.numRows,
        sortCol = assert.simpleSqlName(data.sortCol),
        sortDir = assert.validSortOrder(data.sortDir);

    var countQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' +
        'FROM this_view ' ;

    var query = 'SELECT * ' +
        'FROM this_view' ;

    var seg,
        orderBy,
        offset;

    orderBy = ' ORDER BY UPPER(' + sortCol + ') ' + sortDir;
    offset = ' OFFSET :start_row ROWS FETCH NEXT :num_rows ROWS ONLY';

    query += orderBy;
    query += offset;

    logger.info("Begin: " + (new Date().toString()));

    async.parallel({
        rows: function (callback) {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                logger.info("Begin Connection: " + (new Date().toString()));
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err.message);
                    return;
                }

                logger.info("Begin execute: " + (new Date().toString()));

                connection.execute(
                    query,
                    {
                      start_row: startRow,
                      num_rows: numRows
                    },
                    function (err, result) {
                        logger.info("End execute: " + (new Date().toString()));
                        if (err) {
                            logger.error(err.message);
                            callback("Something broke in the first thing");
                            doRelease(connection);
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log(result.rows);

                        var procJson = [];

                        /**
                         *  For each row in the result, pushes a new object to the rows array
                         *  In each new object, the key is assigned and the result row value set
                         */
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                            procJson.push({});
                            for (var j = 0; j < result.metaData.length; j++) {
                                procJson[i][result.metaData[j].name.toLowerCase()] = result.rows[i][j];
                            }
                        }

                        logger.info("Send JSON: " + (new Date().toString()));
                        callback(null, procJson);
                        logger.info("JSON Sent: " + (new Date().toString()));

                        doRelease(connection);
                    });
            });
        },
        totalRows: function (callback) {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                logger.info("Begin Connection: " + (new Date().toString()));
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err.message);
                    return;
                }

                logger.info("Begin execute: " + (new Date().toString()));

                connection.execute(
                    countQuery,
                    function (err, result) {
                        logger.info("End execute: " + (new Date().toString()));
                        if (err) {
                            logger.error(err.message);
                            callback("Something broke");
                            doRelease(connection);
                            return;
                        }

                        logger.info("Send JSON: " + (new Date().toString()));
                        console.log(result.rows);
                        callback(null, result.rows[0][0]);
                        logger.info("JSON Sent: " + (new Date().toString()));

                        doRelease(connection);
                    });
            });
        }
    }, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            logger.error(err);
        }

        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Learn more about bind variables here: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#bind

Also, check out the slides from a recent talk I gave. You may get something out of them... https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rhnu74z2y21gsy/Tips%20and%20Tricks%20for%20Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Oracle%20Database%20Driver%20for%20Node.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Thanks Dan. I updated my code with the ResultSet changes and have posted my error. I will also update mycode with the asset and bindvariable code. totalRows works fine. Not the rows module. Do you mind enlightening me on how to proceed considering the log I posted?

Comment: Are you sure you've updated the code? I see the error reflects the resultSet, but the code doesn't. Here's another example of using a resultSet with async/await: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/772#issuecomment-338054670

Comment: Sorry. I updated the code now. I do get the error "Cannot read property 'getConnection' of undefined" now.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am using Node 6 and when I try to run the aync/await code, I get this.

while (row = await result.resultSet.getRow()
                             ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Yeah, you need Node.js v7.6+ for async/await... Let me review the code.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. So it looks like result.row or result.rows returns undefined whereas result.metadata is an array of objects with the "name" key.

Comment: Your current code appears to be a snippet of the overall module (which is fine). But where is "pool" defined? That's the object you're calling getConnection off of. Post the updated code when you have it.

Comment: That's correct. Metadata is used to get the info on the columns you're querying. There's extendedMetadata too, but I'm not sure you need it. Review that here: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#-42541-metadata. Regarding result.rows being undefined, please review the doc here: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#resultsethandling. The API is different than a standard execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157936/discussion-between-a2441918-and-dan-mcghan).

Comment: Hey Dan, I have updated the code with the pool information.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I got it. Followed the guide on github and it worked.

Comment: I updated my code where I encounter a minor issue on how to handle "0" results. Could you enlighten me on that please?

Comment: You're invoking the callback in the if branch that says you have rows. Why not invoke the callback when you don't have more rows (// no rows)? Also, you're running two separate queries, one to get a total row count and another to get the data. This is not efficient or consistent. Look into using the analytic count function: select count(*) over () as total from table

Comment: Can you please provide me an edited snippet of the same?

Comment: No, this is a new question entirely. Just look at where you're calling callback(null, procJson); Post a new question if needed.

Comment: Sure Dan. Thanks. Will do if I am not able to fix it.

Comment: I fixed the 0 records issue, but now if I paginate, it seems to pull the new set of 10 records in the backend but sends an empty array to the UI. Any leads to fix this?

Comment: callback(null, procJson); needs to be inside of fetchRowsFromRS - inside the last "else" block for no rows.